# Android: LinearLayout with Horizontal Orientation pushes elements off the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

***I have a LinearLayout:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Which I fill with dynamically added fragments**

```
void add_item(){
        Database database = new Database(this);
        String[] categories = database.getCategories();
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (categories.length>0) {
            for (String category : categories){
                FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
                int id = View.generateViewId();
                frame.setId(id);
                layout.addView(frame);
                Fragment itemsFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.body, category);
                ft.add(id, itemsFragment);
            }
            Log.i("test","success");
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
```

The problem is that the fragments go out of the screen. I actually want the fragments horizontally and move below only when i run out of space. Is it possible?

Comment: Should you not change the orientation of the linear layout to vertical?

Comment: @AjilO. If i do so they will line up as column

Comment: Ok. That was a bit unclear from just reading the question once.To get better responses you should probably add to the question that you actually want the fragments horizontally and move below only when you run out of space. :)

Comment: Try using a grid layout.

Answer (score 2):

LinearLayout can't do that unfortunately. You would have to add up all the widths of each view and then when they exceed the width of the screen, create a new LinearLayout below and start filling that up. Not exactly elegant.

To solve this problem, Google created the Flexbox library to mimic the desired behaviour that is available in CSS. [Take a look at it here](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Comment: I think i will make a fragment so it fits the screen width and change the orientation to vertical. And later i will try your method.

Comment: Flexbox looks super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your orientation of linear layout is "horizonal", so it will try to push all of the child in a row, not column.

Also, you should really try to work with RecyclerView, not with LinearLayout because of overhead storing all of the views in memory and keeping them drawing. [Here is how to do it by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).